# Symfony EasyAuditBundle error when insert into table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, audit

I got this error when it try to insert into the audit_lo table

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO audit_log (id,
>   type_id, type, description, event_time, user, impersonatingUser, ip)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [5,
>   "security.interactive_login", "security.interactive_login",
>   "security.interactive_login", "2017-11-22 12:56:48", "bmellor", null,
>   "::1"]:

and this log

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException:
>   "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO audit_log (id,
>   type_id, type, description, event_time, user, impersonatingUser, ip)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [5,
>   "security.interactive_login", "security.interactive_login",
>   "security.interactive_login", "2017-11-22 12:56:48", "bmellor", null,
>   "::1"]: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error in or
>   close to «user» LINE 1: ..._log (id, type_id, type, description,
>   event_time, user, impe... ^" at
>   /project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php
>   line 70

I follow all the steps in [here](https://github.com/xiidea/EasyAuditBundle) and inside `config.yml`

```
xiidea_easy_audit:
    entity_class : AppBundle\Entity\AuditLog                     #Required
    user_property : username                            #Optional
    doctrine_entities :                                              #Optional
         AppBundle\Entity\SomeEntity : [created, updated, deleted]
    events :                                                   #Optional
        - security.interactive_login
```

---

EDIT

Environment
PHP 7.1.11
Symfony 3.3.X
PostgreSQL 9.6
EasyAuditBundle ^1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answer this question with 2 steps:

1. It seems like postgreSQL the column USER is reserved so I change it to user_data inside the entity
2. Changed impersonatingUser to nullable=true

And that works for me.